# How do i get this for loop to work?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, string.format

I made a helper method to sort an array with numbers in it.

Then i call the method in my "main" method and have it return a using string.format.

This code works when the string.format portion is outside of the for loop and if statement but when its inside the i doesn't return anything when i tell it to.

I know the issue might have to do with my if statement but i'm having trouble finding a solution.

```
public static String getSmallestSalaryString(String[] names, int[] ages, double[] salaries) {
    String str= "";
    String str2="";
    String str3="";
    double[] sal= smallestSal(salaries);

    for(int i= 0; i < sal.length; i++) {
        if(sal[i]== 0) {
             str= String.format("Smallest salary:$%,.2f, Name:%s, age:%d" , sal[0], names[0], ages[0]);
             return str;
        }

        else if(sal[i]== 1) {
             str2= String.format("Smallest salary:$%,.2f, Name:%s, age:%d" , sal[1], names[1], ages[1]);
            return str2;
        }

        else if(sal[i] == 2) {
             str3= String.format("Smallest salary:$%,.2f, Name:%s, age:%d" , sal[2], names[2], ages[2]);
            return str3;
        }
    }


    return str;
}

public static double[] smallestSal(double[] salaries) {
    Arrays.sort(salaries);

    return salaries;
}
```

Comment: please post the entire code! moreover, it might not be returning anything simply because the array contains no salary where salary = 0

Comment: I've added the whole code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution requires you to find an "address" and not the "content".

I am assuming here that `salaries` contains the salary of all the employees, `names` is their name and `ages` their age. I am also assuming that `ages`, `names` and `salaries` have the same size and correlates per index. Then with these information, you construct a string to indicate the employee with the lowest salary in the company.

Since none of these information are structured within a single object, you need to find the lowest salary **INDEX** only. With that information, you can give his/her name and age by accessing `ages[INDEX]` and `names[INDEX]`.

What you are currently doing is finding the lowest salary and then guess its INDEX in the loop, which would be more complex. Instead, in your method "smallestSal", get the INDEX in the array of the smallest salary. Then with that, your loop becomes simple. See below what I mean.

```
public static String getSmallestSalaryString(String[] names, int[] ages, double[] salaries) {
    int lowestSalaryIdx= getLowestSalaryIndex(salaries);

    return String.format("Smallest salary:$%,.2f, Name:%s, age:%d" , salaries[lowestSalaryIdx], names[lowestSalaryIdx], ages[lowestSalaryIdx]);
}

public static int getLowestSalaryIndex(double[] salaries) {
    int lowestSalaryIndex = 0;
    double lowestSalary = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<salaries.length; ++i) {
      if (salaries[i] < lowestSalary) {
        lowestSalaryIndex = i;
        lowestSalary = salaries[i];
      }
    }

    return lowestSalaryIndex;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right with all of your assumptions!! I will try your suggestion and ask gain if i need more help! Thank you!!!

Comment: It is my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating through your array  you should change sal[0], names[0], ages[0] to sal[i], names[i], ages[i] .

```
for(int i= 0; i < sal.length; i++) {
    if(sal[i]== 0) {
         str= String.format("Smallest salary:$%,.2f, Name:%s, age:%d" , sal[i], names[i], ages[i]);
         return str;
    }
```

Comment: I have posted all whole thing now

Answer (score 0):

After sorting you get the smallest salary in 1st element(index 0). Then you should find the actual index of that value in original array and get the details from that index. So your code should be modified as follows.

```
public static String getSmallestSalaryString(String[] names, int[] ages, double[] salaries) {
    String str = "";
    String str2 = "";
    String str3 = "";
    ArrayList sal = smallestSal(salaries);

    double smallestSalary = (double) sal.get(0);
    int salIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < salaries.length; i++) {
        if (salaries[i] == smallestSalary) {
            salIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    str = String.format("Smallest salary:$%,.2f, Name:%s, age:%d", salaries[salIndex], names[salIndex], ages[salIndex]);

    return str;
}

public static ArrayList smallestSal(double[] salaries) {
    ArrayList salaryList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < salaries.length; i++) {
        salaryList.add(salaries[i]);
    }
    Collections.sort(salaryList);

    return salaryList;
}
```

Comment: I've done something similar to that, but it only works if there is only one thing in each given array. If there is multiple things in each array it doesn't work for it.

Comment: Guess you need to get only the smallest salary details. Please refer to the edited answer.

Comment: Arrays.sort will sort the original array and after that we cannot find the original index to fetch data from other arrays. So it is better to use another data structure to get sorted values.